# using WP_Query post object inside another object

Tags: php, wordpress

see this class

```
class block {

    function item_html( $post ) {
        ?> <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong> <?
    }

    function render( $posts ) {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
            $this->item_html($post);
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata();        
    }
}
```

this is just example, in my code it must to make another function called `item_html`, i not want the code inside the while, ok?

now i want to use the `the_title();` and the related functions in the `item_html`,should i pass `$post` in the args of `item_html` or just make global like that

```
    function item_html(){
      global $post;
        ?> <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong> <?
    }
```

the creazy thing in that way if i remove the global and the arg called $post, its working , how that happen? and what is the best way to assign single post to another function

Comment: get_post(id)->post_title ? not sure

Comment: You must mean to write `$post->the_title()` and why do you write `?> <?`

Comment: u have to make a custom new wp_query or get post by id if it won't be a loop